# Want to play 2 audio files at once

Tags: music, background-process

Is there an audio app that will play a stereo file in the background, even if I start playing audio in another app?  In other words, when I try this using Google play music and Poweramp, Google play will do it but pauses itself when I start a new track in Poweramp.  I would like it to continue playing as background to everything I'm doing.

Thanks!

Comment: Or, I need another player (besides Poweramp) that has an audio focus setting (like Poweramp does).  That would allow me to tell the app to keep playing no matter what.

Answer (score 2):

Certain players have an "audio focus" setting that will allow it to ignore other apps and actions.  I found Rocket Player and Poweramp are two of them.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [DUAL Music Player](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.a1b.dualmusicplayer&hl=en) and [Multi Audio Player](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=prizoff.com.multiaudioplayer)